# problems with cross validation code - r -

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I'm writing a function to perform logistic regression on two columns of a dataframe. I can't get around the errors... I am trying to use 10-fold cross validation. Here's the code I'm using:

```
SAdata = read.table("http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/SAheart.data", 
                     sep=",",head=T,row.names=1)

log.fun = function(x,y) {

    prediction = data.frame()
    tset = data.frame()
    dframe = cbind(x,y)
    dframe = as.data.frame(dframe)
    dframe$fold = sample(1:10, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
    list = 1:10

    for (i in 1:10) { 

        train = subset(dframe, fold %in% list[-i])
        test = subset(dframe, fold %in% c(i))
        model = glm(x~y, data=train, family=binomial)
        pred = as.data.frame(predict(model, test[,-1]))
        prediction <- rbind(prediction, pred)

    }
}

log.fun(SAdata$chd,SAdata$obesity)
```

The error I get is "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid 'size' argument"

Any ideas?

Comment: From the error, i'd guess the problem is in the `dframe$fold = sample(1:10, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)` line. You don't have `data` defined anywhere. What did you expect that to do?

Comment: Thank you. I fiddled with the code... that should be dframe instead of data.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda sub-optimal use of for loops and specially modelling... if you want to try some good models developing try the package 'caret'

If you still want to use that function here is a workaround

```
SAdata = read.table("http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/SAheart.data",sep=",",head=T,row.names=1)

log.fun=function(x,y){

  prediction = data.frame()
  tset=data.frame()
  dframe=cbind(x,y)
  dframe=as.data.frame(dframe)
  dframe$fold = sample(1:10, nrow(dframe), replace = TRUE)
  list = 1:10

  results <- list()
  for (i in 1:10) {     

    results[[paste0('Fold',i)]]$train <- subset(dframe, fold %in% list[-i])
    results[[paste0('Fold',i)]]$test <- subset(dframe, fold %in% c(i))
    results[[paste0('Fold',i)]]$model <- glm(x~y, data=results[[i]]$train, family=binomial)
    results[[paste0('Fold',i)]]$pred <- as.data.frame(predict(results[[i]]$model, results[[i]]$test[,-1]))
    results[[paste0('Fold',i)]]$prediction <- rbind(prediction, results[[i]]$pred)

}
results}


your_results<-log.fun(SAdata$chd,SAdata$obesity)

head(your_results$Fold1$prediction)
```

In fact you had some problems in the function 'sample' since you were specifying 'data' and that object did not exist ... I replace it for dframe and added some names to each part of your results.

Hope it helps